# flask-restful: how to parse parameters when connected to sql server db?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I want to create a REST API using python flask. So anytime I do this:

localhost/customers?cust_country=USA

I want to fetch every row from table 'customers' where everyone is from USA.

This is the script I've so far:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask_restful import reqparse

e = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://....")

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('cust_country', type = 'string')

class Dep(Resource):
    def get(self):
        conn = e.connect()
        args = parser.parse_args()
        query = conn.execute("select * from customers where cust_country = ?", [args['cust_country']])
        print(query)
        return {'custid': [i[0] for i in query.cursor.fetchall()]}

api.add_resource(Dep, '/customers')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

I'm getting this error:

> C:\Users\x>curl 127.0.0.1:5000/customers?cust_country=USA  404 Not
>   Found
>
> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on
>   the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your
>   spelling and try again.

======================

part 2: sending multiple parameters:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_restful import reqparse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


e = create_engine("x")

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('cust_country', type = str)
parser.add_argument('cust_name', type = str)

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Dep(Resource):
    def get(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        conn = e.connect()
        query = conn.execute("select cust_id from customers where cust_country = ? and cust_name = ?", [args['cust_country'], args['cust_name']])
        return {'custid': [i[0] for i in query.cursor.fetchall()]}

api.add_resource(Dep, '/customers')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

this is what I'm using in my curl:

> curl "127.0.0.1:5000/customers?cust_country=USA&cust_name=Wascals"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One error that you may be facing is by using
`parser.add_argument('cust_country', type = 'string')` which is wrong.

It should be `parser.add_argument('cust_country', type = str)`.

Also I would suggest to use `app.run(debug=True)` as it will help you debug simple errors.

Comment: I changed it to type = str but I'm still getting the same error when I do this: 

curl 127.0.0.1:5000/customers -d "cust_country=USA"

Comment: `-d "cust_country=USA"` would not work since you only wrote the endpoint for a `get` request.

Try using this snippet for the sake of testing
https://gist.github.com/yashmehrotra/207cb1a58a4653c75cb8 

With the command `curl "127.0.0.1:5000/customers?cust_country=USA"`

Comment: getting this output: {"hello": "USA"}

Comment: Now you can replace the lines 15-16 with your code, since you are now able to capture the `cust_country` argument in b. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: hey yash! can you please check the updated post? how do I pass multiple parameters?

Comment: The code you wrote for multiple parameters is working fine and give the expected output. In my `args` dictionary, I am getting both `cust_country` and `cust_name`.

Comment: @YashMehrotra can we use reqparse.RequestParser() for post request? I mean i'm getting success when trying using curl but getting error when trying using POSTMAN

Comment: I don't know, I never tried it. I usually use, `request.body` or `request.form` for that purpose